# UPDATE and DELETE a set of rows when the operations affect the set

Tags: mysql, sql

Background info: *We have a community room, which can be divided in half via a curtain. In the past when a group needed the full room we put 2 entries in, one for each half... However we've modified the software (MRBS) so that there are now 3 rooms (Full{1},Closet Side{2}, and Kitchen Side{3}) and the software checks that you can't reserve a partial room when the full is already booked and vice versa. However we have plenty of old "full room" reservations made by reserving both sides. So when 2 & 3 are identical I need to move one of the bookings to 1 and delete the other.*

So I have a table such as:

```
id  room_id  start_time   name
1   2        13:00        Meeting
2   2        15:00        Meeting
3   3        15:00        Meeting
4   3        13:00        Storytime
```

I want to go through the table, and when room 2 & 3 both have entries at the same time and with the same name I want to change room 2's room_id to 1 and delete the entry for room 3. So in the above example entry 2 would be modified and entry 3 would be deleted.

I'm fairly certain this needs to be two separate queries; EG first where there is a match change all of the room_id's for 2 to 1, then as a separate query, compare room 1&3 and delete entries on 3.

I *think* this is close for changing room 2 to 1:

```
UPDATE `mrbs_entry`
JOIN `mrbs_entry` AS `other_side` ON `other_side.room_id` = '3'
    AND `other_side.name` = `mrbs_entry.name`
    AND `other_side.start_time` = `mrbs_entry.start_time`
    AND `other_side.id` != `mrbs_entry.id`
SET `mrbs_entry.room_id` = '1'
WHERE (`mrbs_entry.room_id` = '2' AND `mrbs_entery.id` IN(92437,92438,92442,92443,92470,92471,92477,92478,92489,89462,92496,90873))
```

however I get an `#1054 - Unknown column 'mrbs_entry.room_id' in 'field list'` error

Note: the IN(*) bit is to limit it to a few test entries to make sure it's actually working as expected.

Comment: I think you'll need multiple queries for the same. Make a stored procedure for the whole thing.

Comment: is there some condition that makes room 2's room_id to 1 ? why 1 not 4 ?

Comment: @xto Actually, in practice it'll be 28 not 1 but I put 1 in the example for simplicity's sake.

Comment: I mean why (in your example) it gets id of first/previous record? because it has the same title?

Comment: Because room_id relates to what room it is... so 1 =Full Room 2=Closet side 3=Kitchen side ... room_id is not unique, it's just which room the meeting is taking place in...

Comment: @RyanVincent There is in fact a lot of other columns, which I left off for clarity... basically we have a meeting room with a curtain that can make it become 2 rooms.  Previously room bookings were a bit complicated because if you wanted the full room you had to make a duplicate booking on both sides. Now that we have a better way we want to move all of the old "both side" bookings ...

Comment: @RyanVincent Fair enough... being on the other side it didn't seem as interesting as the actual problem... but I've been working on this project for a few weeks and this is basically the last snag, so my POV might be a bit biased.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they already solved those issues, Ryan, and are just trying to update the database to match the new system.

Comment: Yeah, @Dave has it right. Not the end of the world if we can't message the data to be perfect, but it would be nice to do it all automatically both for statistical purposes and so if a booking change only 1 edit has to be made not two (bookings can be made 3 or more months in advance, so there are a lot of potential snags) plus not all of our users are particularly tech savvy, so we want to only give them one way to interact w/ the software not "entries created before date X do A, entries create after do B".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 - Stored Procedure with temporary table**

This seems the simplest method if you're prepared to use a Stored Procedure and temporary table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_sanitize_mrbs()
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS mrbs_to_sanitize;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mrbs_to_sanitize (
      id int auto_increment primary key,
      room2_id int,
      room3_id int);

    -- "I want to go through the table, and when room 2 & 3 both have
    -- entries at the same time and with the same name I want to..."
    INSERT INTO mrbs_to_sanitize (room2_id, room3_id)
    SELECT m1.id, m2.id
    FROM mrbs_entry m1
    CROSS JOIN mrbs_entry m2
    WHERE m1.start_time = m2.start_time
      AND m1.name = m2.name
      AND m1.room_id = 2
      AND m2.room_id = 3;

    -- ...change room 2's room_id to 1
    UPDATE mrbs_entry me
    JOIN mrbs_to_sanitize mts
    ON me.id = mts.room2_id
    SET me.room_id = 1;

    -- "...and delete the entry for room 3."
    DELETE me
    FROM mrbs_entry me
    JOIN mrbs_to_sanitize mts
    ON me.id = mts.room3_id;
END//

-- ...
-- The Stored Procedure can now be called any time you like:
CALL sp_sanitize_mrbs();
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo - using a Stored Procedure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f17b/1)

**Method 2 - *without* Stored Procedure**

The following "trick" is slightly more complex but should do it without using stored procedures, temporary tables or variables:

```
-- "I want to go through the table, and when room 2 & 3 both have
-- entries at the same time and with the same name I want to..."

-- "...change room 2's room_id to 1"
UPDATE mrbs_entry m1
CROSS JOIN mrbs_entry m2
-- temporarily mark this row as having been updated
SET m1.room_id = 1, m1.name = CONCAT(m1.name, ' UPDATED')
WHERE m1.start_time = m2.start_time
  AND m1.name = m2.name
  AND m1.room_id = 2
  AND m2.room_id = 3;

-- "...and delete the entry for room 3."
DELETE m2 FROM mrbs_entry m1
CROSS JOIN mrbs_entry m2
WHERE m1.start_time = m2.start_time
  AND m1.name = CONCAT(m2.name, ' UPDATED')
  AND m1.room_id = 1
  AND m2.room_id = 3;

-- now remove the temporary marker to restore previous value
UPDATE mrbs_entry
SET name = LEFT(name, CHAR_LENGTH(name) - CHAR_LENGTH(' UPDATED'))
WHERE name LIKE '% UPDATED';
```

**Explanation of Method 2**

The first query updates the room number. However, as you mentioned, we need to perform the delete in a separate query. Since I'm not making any assumptions about your data, a safe way of requerying to get the same results once they have been modified is to introduce a "marker" to temporarily indicate which row was changed by the update. *In the example above, this marker is `'UPDATED '` but you may wish to choose something more likely to never be used for any other purpose e.g. a random sequence of characters. It could also be moved onto a different field if required.* The delete can then be performed and finally the marker needs to be removed to restore the original data.

See [SQL Fiddle demo - *without* Stored Procedure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9656f/1).

Comment: -1: the first method only works when there is only one entry in the table that needs adjusting. Unless I'm very mistaking, @room_id can only hold 1 value so you'd have to run the stored procedure over and over again until you finally have caught all situations. Far from optimal. To test: simply add 2 extra lines for both half-rooms on 18:00 with name Test and check the output of your SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Approach 2 does seem to work, but it assumes you have sufficient space to store the result of the concatenated string in the `name` field. It probably works but you can't be sure! (also what if happens if some name already started with ' UPDATED' .. again unlikely, but not impossible)

Comment: Firstly IMO this seems like a "tactical" downvote as you have obviously read the answer and gained something from it. Regarding your points,  the first one is a good spot - will think about how it could be tweaked - perhaps using a temporary table instead. But re: the second point, please read the bit in italics in the explanation. Without knowing the whole possible dataset I chose a marker that is easy to read and understand but it could easily be changed to something else, even for example replacing the colon in the start_time field to another single character.

Comment: LOL, 'tactical vote' ...as if I care about the points. Anyway, I admit I had skipped over the italics part, focusing on the code. The -1 is purely because of the fact that your approach is 'row-based' and yet is presented as being 'set-based'. Feel free to fix it and I'll redraw my -1; but like it is right now it reminds me too much on how people write triggers and then complain it only acts on the first row.

Comment: Have just fixed to address point 1. Guess we're all different on here but personally I only downvote answers that are very poorly put together or give particularly bad advice - not those that add anything helpful to a discussion or those that contain an error that can be modified to become correct - we're all human after all.

Comment: True. But assuming that the answer that gets read the most is the one on top (read: gets most votes) I tend to try to move wrong answers (or bad advice as you say) to the bottom by down-voting them. I also try to keep track of the things I vote upon; if my reason to up or down-vote 'disappears' then so does the vote. Anyway, +1 again.

Comment: @SteveChambers Nice method 2. You can also temporarily mark records with unique artificial temporary `room_id = 0`. That way there are no issues with 'UPDATED' already in the `name` or potential `name` overflow as well as performance benefit of no strings manipulations. And wrapping it in a transaction would be a cherry on top.

Comment: @Y.B. Good idea - but there's a possible snag here in that it makes a small assumption about the schema - i.e. that there isn't a foreign key constraint that would prevent `room_id` from being set to a non-existent room. Subtleties like this was the reason I decided to keep it simple and use a simple marker - although I do take the point that this is also making an assumption about spare capacity on the field that may not be valid. Hopefully the OP should be able to take the solution as a pattern to build on and choose the most suitable marker. Re: Transaction, good point, will update later...

Comment: Thanks @SteveChambers, Method 2 worked perfectly! Very much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @aslum - good to hear it worked out there in the real world! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the table name for an update in the line for SET.
You could probably get away with changing that line to just

```
SET `room_id` = '1'
```

But this is probably safer from the standpoint of ensuring the query works like you want it to:

```
UPDATE 
`mrbs_entry`
set `room_id` = '1'
WHERE `id` IN
(
    SELECT `mrbs_entry.id` FROM
    `mrbs_entry`
    JOIN `mrbs_entry` AS `other_side` ON `other_side.room_id` = '3'
        AND `other_side.name` = `mrbs_entry.name`
        AND `other_side.start_time` = `mrbs_entry.start_time`
        AND `other_side.id` != `mrbs_entry.id`
    WHERE (`mrbs_entry.room_id` = '2' AND `mrbs_entry.id` IN(92437,92438,92442,92443,92470,92471,92477,92478,92489,89462,92496,90873))
) AS T
```

Run the inner query until it's pulling the right group of `id`s, then run the whole thing to change the `room_id`s

Comment: I assume the T at the end is a typo?

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous ...I've tried putting mrbs_entry.id in and either get the same error, or unknown column 'mrbs_entry.id'

Comment: The T and the end is the name of the sub-query

Comment: It's complaining about the id in the sub-query, I think.  Updated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the subquery section... If I just straight up include it I get #1064 - error in SQL syntax

Comment: If you run just the subquery, between the outer parenthesis, does that work?  I mostly do sql server, so my syntax is probably off

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implemented a trigger or more exactly  a store procedure that returns a trigger.

1) Check the entries have the same title. 
2) UPDATE room to 2 to room 1.
3) DELETE entry for room 3.

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in 2 steps. The first step would be non-destructive.  This way I could see if the first step looked correct before moving on to the actual modifications to `mrbs_entry`.

First create a temp table with the self-join to discover exact matches of rooms 2 and 3.  This extra table would effectively list the reservations that need to go in as room 1, plus it lists the reservations for 2 and 3 that need deleting.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp
    SELECT a.*
        FROM mrbs_entry AS a
        JOIN mrbs_entry AS b  ON a... = b...
        WHERE a.room_id = 2
          AND b.room_id = 3;
```

The `ON` is `start_time` and/or `date` and/or `name` or some combo of them.  Note that only one set of columns (`a.*`) is captured.

That table is deliberately not a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`, but rather a 'permanent' table.  Check the contents to see if was created correctly.

The second step breaks into 2 queries, but in a single transaction for some extra security:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE mrbs_entry
    FROM mrbs_entry
    JOIN tmp ON mrbs_entry... = tmp...
    WHERE mrbs_entry.room_id IN (2,3);   -- delete both reservations
INSERT INTO mrbs_entry
     SELECT 1 as room_id, ...
         FROM tmp;     -- Insert the "full" assignments
COMMIT;
```

And finally clean up -- after you have further confirmed that the changes were good,

```
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I think it's pretty self explanatory and follows your logic of using two queries.

```
-- update query
update mrbs_entry 
join 
(
    select t1.* 
    from mrbs_entry as t1 
    join mrbs_entry as t2 
        on 
        t2.room_id <> t1.room_id -- get different rooms
    and t2.start_time = t1.start_time  -- with same start time
    and t2.name = t1.name -- and same name
    where 
        t1.room_id = 2 -- where the left side has room id 2
    and t2.room_id = 3 -- and the right side has room id 3
) as t 
    on 
        t.id = mrbs_entry.id -- set those room ids (2) to
    set mrbs_entry.room_id = 1 ; -- the new id (1)

-- delete query
delete mrbs_entry 
from mrbs_entry 
join mrbs_entry as t1 
    on 
        t1.room_id <> mrbs_entry.room_id -- same as above, different room ids
    and t1.start_time = mrbs_entry.start_time -- same start time
    and t1.name = mrbs_entry.name -- same name
    where 
        mrbs_entry.room_id = 3 -- get the stuff that has room id 3 (to get rid of it)
    and t1.room_id = 1 -- and new duplicate room id 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your statement a little bit and it [worked](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b57c0/1) correctly (at least at first glance).

```
UPDATE mrbs_entry AS tab1
INNER JOIN (SELECT other_side.id, other_side.name, other_side.start_time
           FROM mrbs_entry AS other_side 
         WHERE other_side.room_id = 3) as tab2
  ON tab1.start_time = tab2.start_time
 AND tab1.name = tab2.name
 AND tab1.id != tab2.id
SET tab1.room_id = 1
 WHERE tab1.room_id = 2
   AND tab1.id IN(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by some of the answers here as the actual problem isn't all that hard IMHO.

- First you need to identify all reservations for all the sub-rooms. In other words, you need a list of reservations with the same name and the same start_time but one for room_id 2 and one for room_id 3. (`GROUP BY` & `HAVING`)
- You then convert this list in room_id 1 entries (`INSERT`)
- Finally you get rid of all room_id 2 and 3 entries when there also is a (freshly inserted) room_id 1 entry. (`DELETE`)

  ```
  -- setup
  CREATE TABLE mrbs_entry (id int auto_increment primary key, room_id int, start_time varchar(255), name varchar(255));
  INSERT INTO mrbs_entry (room_id, start_time, name) VALUES (2, '13:00', 'Meeting');
  INSERT INTO mrbs_entry (room_id, start_time, name) VALUES (2, '15:00', 'Meeting');
  INSERT INTO mrbs_entry (room_id, start_time, name) VALUES (3, '15:00', 'Meeting');
  INSERT INTO mrbs_entry (room_id, start_time, name) VALUES (3, '13:00', 'Storytime');

  INSERT INTO mrbs_entry (room_id, start_time, name) VALUES (2, '18:00', 'Test');
  INSERT INTO mrbs_entry (room_id, start_time, name) VALUES (3, '18:00', 'Test');

  -- step 1: "convert" reservations that book all 'sub-rooms' into a 'full-room' reservation
  INSERT `mrbs_entry` (room_id, start_time, name)
  SELECT 1, -- full room
          start_time, 
          name
      FROM `mrbs_entry` new
      WHERE room_id IN (2, 3) -- reserved left and/or right side

      -- safety check, avoid inserting the value if it already exists!
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                          FROM `mrbs_entry` old
                          WHERE old.room_id    = 1
                          AND old.start_time = new.start_time
                          AND old.name       = new.name )

  -- must have reserved both sides of the room
      GROUP BY start_time,
              name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

  -- step 2: get rid of all 'sub-room' reservations in case there already is a 'full-room' reservation
  DELETE del
      FROM `mrbs_entry` del
      JOIN `mrbs_entry` fr -- WHERE exists a room_id 1 for same time & name
      ON fr.room_id    = 1
      AND fr.start_time = del.start_time
      AND fr.name       = del.name
  WHERE del.room_id IN (2, 3); -- get rid of half-rooms
  ```

PS: I'd prefer to have used the `WHERE EXISTS` syntax in step 2, but couldn't it get to work right away.. will see if I can find the time later today (I usually work in TSQL which is slightly different)

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Steve Chambers solution Method 2 I would do that in three steps of one transaction.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE mrbs_entry (id int auto_increment primary key, room_id int, start_time varchar(255), name varchar(255));
INSERT INTO mrbs_entry
    (room_id, start_time, name)
VALUES
    (2, '13:00', 'Meeting'),
    (2, '15:00', 'Meeting'),
    (3, '15:00', 'Meeting'),
    (3, '13:00', 'Storytime');
```

Solution:

```
START TRANSACTION;

    -- 1. Mark one "side" of the pair with temporary artificial room_id = 0.
    UPDATE mrbs_entry side2
    INNER JOIN mrbs_entry side3 ON side3.room_id = 3 AND
      side2.start_time = side3.start_time AND
      side2.name = side3.name
    SET side2.room_id = 0
    WHERE side2.room_id = 2;

    -- 2. Delete the other "side" of the pair.
    DELETE side3 FROM mrbs_entry side3
    INNER JOIN mrbs_entry side0 ON side0.room_id = 0 AND
      side0.start_time = side3.start_time AND
      side0.name = side3.name
    WHERE side3.room_id = 3;

    -- 3. Reset the mark to a valid value.
    UPDATE mrbs_entry
    SET room_id = 1
    WHERE room_id = 0;

COMMIT;
```

**This will not work** if there are constraints on `room_id`, but if there are none that would be the safest and most efficient solution. Even if there are constraints, `room_id = 0` can be temporarily added to the list of possible values at the start of the transaction and removed before commit.